# ios Development: Apple Certificate - Certificate Is Not Trusted

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate

I have recently encountered an issue when creating an iOS Developer certificate adn adding it to my Keychain Access. When I view the key in Keychain Access, I get the message 'iPhone Developer: xxx (xxx)" certificate is not trusted.

These are my steps and info:
Create the .cer file
Upload to Apples Dev Account when creating a Certificate
Add the Certificate to Keychain Access. This is where I can see it's not trusted.

When I evaluate the certificate in Certificate Assistant, the Evaluation Status says 'No root certificate found', and Certificate Status is 'Good'. I can see the Issuer Organisational Unit is G3. When I look on https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ I can see G3 only expires in 2030.

How can I get my certificate Trusted? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like a bug to be reported to Apple.